# How may I configure the storage options for a Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, storage, settings

I am currently developing a Python script to launch a new Docker container on an Ubuntu system. The storage driver is overlay2, and the file system is ext4. However, when attempting to run the Docker container and setting the storage options, I encountered an error message. The error reads as follows:

"Error running container: 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.43/containers/create?name=ssh-container: Internal Server Error ("--storage-opt is supported only for overlay over xfs with 'pquota' mount option")"

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: mount a filesystem at /var/lib/docker that meets dockers requirements.

Comment: It appears that in case of overlay2 storage driver, storage_opt is only available if the backing filesystem is xfs and mounted with the pquota mount option.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the error message you're encountering indicates that the ***--storage-opt*** you're trying to set is only supported for overlay2 with the 'pquota' mount option on an XFS file system.

Use the appropriate storage driver, you can change the storage driver by editing Docker's daemon configuration file, typically located at **'/etc/docker/daemon.json'**.

```
{
"storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

If you cannot or do not want to use the overlay2 driver with the specified storage options, you might consider using a different storage driver that supports your desired configuration.

```
dockerd --storage-driver=overlay2 #Or zfs, aufs
```

After making any necessary changes, restart Docker to apply the new settings.

```
sudo service docker restart
```

NOTE: Do ensure that you have an XFS file system, If you're not already using XFS, you might need to format or convert your file system to XFS.

For your reference(docker daemon configuration file):

```
{
 "storage-driver": "overlay2",
 "storage-opts": [
  "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true",
  "overlay2.override_os_check=true",
  "overlay2.size=512M",
  "overlay2.override_base_image_cleanup=true"
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your understanding. Could you please review the issue again? As I mentioned, the current system's storage driver is overlay2.